# issues when using pseudo-classes

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class

I got some problem when I read <CSS: The Definitive Guide>.
In page 55, "**Real-world issues with dynamic styling**" part, The author raised an example:

```
a:link, a:visited {font-size: 13px;}
a:hover {font-size: 20px;}
```

and said:

> However, the CSS specifications state that user agents are not required to redraw a document once it's been rendered for initial display, so you can't absolutely rely on your intended effect taking place. I **strongly recommend that you avoid designs that depend on such behavior**.

I thought the author didn't explain clearly. And it's more complex to realize such behavior by using javascript. Why shouldn't I use pseudo-classes like this?

Are there any guy could tell me **in which case such behavior will cause bad consequences**?

Comment: speed tracer is a chrome extension which will show you when redraws etc take place. There is a similar tool for firefox. For IE everybody is actually working in the dark. It is difficult for anyone to be clear when browsers are not actually being clear about when they redraw etc. The issue with changing font size is fairly clear, if the font gets bigger everything next to it needs to move, that is a page redraw.

Comment: @Wayne, what's the meaning of redrawing to pseudo-class?

Comment: redraw is one of the vast sources of pain and misery that frontend engineers find themselves confronted with. The browser stops what it is doing, and repaints the screen, and makes everything on the screen jump a little bit. Douglas Crockford in "An Inconvenient API - The Theory of the DOM" gives a talk about the real world issues ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs

Comment: @Wayne, thanks for your explanation and the video you shared!

Answer (score 1):

When your browser does not support pseudo-classes, these styles will be ignored. You can still use js/jsquery. But most modern browsers now support pseudo-classes.